# Android store data directory

Tags: android

Hi all I have a create directory function like this:

```
public boolean createDirectory() {
    if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().contains(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+GlobalConfig.CONFIG_BACKUP_DATADIR;
        if( isNeedDL( rootPath )) {
            File myDir = new File(rootPath);
            return myDir.mkdirs();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

May I know if this function should be create a folder correctly for each device?  can this function cover all case? something like SD card unmounted.. etc

Thanks all.

Comment: What is your min API?

Comment: this code is set in my manifest <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>